# How to parse RSS with Code Igniter?

Tags: parsing, codeigniter, rss

I want to parse [this RSS](http://bitly.com/u/joaoramos.rss) (from a bit.ly user stream) to grab all bit.ly links and related data, and store all new items into a database. What are examples of easy ways to parse RSS (e.g. simple helpers with small footprint)? I'm a Code Igniter rookie, so please be gentle :)

Comment: Derek Allard wrote a [tutorial](http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/building-an-rss-feed-in-code-igniter) some years ago, its pretty lightweight.

Comment: @Philip no .. question about PARSE RSS not BUILD RSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by simply using `json_decode(file_get_contents('http://bitly.com/u/joaoramos.json'));` and then dug into the object to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/). Integrating this in CI , shouldn't be hard .

Or If you want one with less foot print, check [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160394/) Thread on CI forums , This is very light and does the job.

Comment: mentioned link is broken!

Comment: @YajliMaclo you can still use SimplePie, but looks like forums have moved to a different URL. Try searching here https://forum.codeigniter.com/search.php ..